# Não consigo acessar a propriedade do objeto. Laravel/Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Não consigo acessar as propriedades do objeto relacionado. Pois bem, tenho uma *class* chamada `FileClass`, ela possui o seguinte relacionamento com a *class* `FileServico`:

**FileClass.php**

```
public function fileServico(){
    return $this->hasMany('FileServico','id_file','id_file');
}
```

**FileServico.php**

```
public function file(){
    return $this->belongsTo('FileClass','id_file','id_file');
}
```

No meu controlador eu recupero os valores da seguinte forma:

**ReservaController.php**

```
public function getIndex(){
    $fileClass = FileClass::with(['FileServico'])->get();
    return View::make('home')->with('fileClass',$fileClass);
}
```

Porém, na view não consigo acessar os objetos do relacionamento, abaixo enumero algumas formas de acessar que tentei:

```
@foreach($fileClass as $f)
    $f->id_servico; //Tentei assim
    $f->file_servico->id_servico //Tentei assim
    $f->fileServico->id_servico; //Assim também
    $f->id_servico //Assim também
    $f->fileServico['id_servico'] //Como array também
    $f->fileServico[0]['id_servico'] //Assim...
@endforeach
```

Entendendo melhor, um file pode possuir vários `file_servico`, se eu simplesmente der um `print_r()` em `$fileClass` que é o objeto q retorna pra view ele não visualiza o objeto relacionado, porém se eu der um `print_r()` em um objeto iterado com `foreach` e tentar acessar sua propriedade separada, ele acessa normalmente `$f->fileServico`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `FileClass` possui um Lista de `FileServico` (`$f->fileServico`) no caso não pode ser acessado sem um `for` ou um `foreach`. Se fosse ao contrário do `FileServico` para FileClass ai daria certo o que você relata na questão. Abaixo um exemplo para clarear.

**Sugerindo um exemplo minimo:**

```
//Tabela fileclass
CREATE TABLE `fileclass` (
  `id_file` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_file`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_file_UNIQUE` (`id_file`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
//Tabela fileservico
CREATE TABLE `fileservico` (
  `id_servico` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_file` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_servico`),
  KEY `id_file_key_idx` (`id_file`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_file_key` FOREIGN KEY (`id_file`) 
  REFERENCES `fileclass` (`id_file`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Dados Exemplos**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Models**

```
class FileClass extends Eloquent 
{
    public $table      = 'fileclass'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'id_file';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function fileServico(){
        return $this->hasMany('FileServico','id_file','id_file');
    }
}
class FileServico extends Eloquent {
    public $table      = 'fileservico'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'id_servico';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function file(){
        return $this->belongsTo('FileClass','id_file','id_file');
    }
}
```

**Eloquent acessando relacionamento com with**

```
$files = FileClass::with('FileServico')->get();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file->id_file.' '.$file->desc;
    echo '<br>';
    $servicos = $file->FileServico;         
    foreach ($servicos as $servico) 
    {
        echo $servico->id_servico.' '.$servico->desc;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Debug:**

```
select * from `fileclass`
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
select * from `fileservico` where `fileservico`.`id_file` in (?, ?)

//id_file = 1
1 File 1
   1 Servico1
   2 Servico2

//id_file = 2
2 File 2
  3 Servico3
```

Answer (score 1):

Objeto retornado caso eu acesse $f->fileServico, que é o relacionamento.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => FileServico Object
            (
                [table:protected] => file_servico
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => id_servico
                    )

                [rules:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [primaryKey:protected] => id_file
                [connection:protected] => 
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id_servico] => 4
                        //Aqui ficam os campos da tabela...
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id_servico] => 4
                        //Aqui ficam os campos da tabela...
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

O acesso a propriedade protegida não foi possível, então, tive que fazer algumas modificações pra conseguir rodar. Pois bem:

No controlador fiz a inclusão do método toArray, assim ele me retorna tudo como array:

```
$fileClass = FileClass::with(['FileServico'])->get()->toArray();
```

A seguir, recuperei na view os valores iterando com dois foreach, vejam:

```
@foreach($fileClass as $file)
    @foreach($file['file_servico'] as $f)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $f['id_servico'] }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Perde um pouco da elegância por não acessar como objeto, mas consegui o que queria, quem tiver outro meio mais prático, agradeceria se puder compartilhar.